# Is there a function to standardize the resultant when a point vector is reflected by a cone?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In a previous question 
[Reflect a point vector in a conical surface and determine average resultant vector.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630833/reflect-a-point-vector-in-a-conical-surface-and-determine-average-resultant-vect/631475?iemail=1&noredirect=1#631475) 
an expression:-

$V1_x =   P_x (1 - 2\sin^2(\gamma))$

$V1_y = - P_y (1 -\sin^2(\gamma))$

$V1_z =   0$.

was derived for the average vector **V1** which results when a point vector **P** $(P_x,P_y,0)$ making angle $\sigma$ with the x-axis is reflected multiply across co-origined lines (**a**) which generate a conical surface with half-angle $\gamma$ to the x-axis.

THIS QUESTION: Is there a function F which, when applied to each individual reflection vector **Q1i**, will produce a modified vector **Q2i** such that the mean of all the **Q2** vectors is a vector **V2** of the form:-

$V2_x =   Kx. P_x $

$V2_y = - Ky. P_y $

$V2_z =   0$.

where Kx and Ky are scalar quantities which are equal to each other and independent of $\gamma$ and $\sigma$?

I am thinking of a function F similar to:- 
$ Q2 = F(Q1) = Q1.(1/cos^2(\phi)) $
where $ \phi $ is the angle between **P** and **a**.

UPDATE
The F function just mentioned above appears to produce values of Kx,Ky which are unequal and dependent on $\gamma$ and $\sigma$.  I am thinking of trying a Fresnel form of function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations).

Comment: $F$ cannot be a scalar function since it produces a vector, not a scalar. Your example and the title actually tell me that maybe you meant a function that changes each component by some factor, is it right?

Comment: Yes sorry. I should have said F is a function which transforms an input vector Q1 into an output vector Q2.